# How to get ca-bundle from openssl

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-ec2, openssl

I have generated the SSL using openssl using the following commands. Which have generated the cert and key file but where do I get the ca-bundle file. I need the ca-bundle file to include in nodejs application else it is showing not secure warning.

```
openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server-csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-csr.pem -signkey server-key.pem -out server-cert.pem
```

my server's code

```
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("path-to-key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("path-to-crt"),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync("path-to-ca-bundle"), fs.readFileSync("path-to-crt")],
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

[image]

Comment: OpenSSL itself does not supply any CA certs, in a bundle or otherwise. Some environments do: if you use Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/etc, or RedHat/CentOS/Oracle/etc, those supply CA certs, sourced from Mozilla. You don't say what OS (if any!) you are running on EC2. nodejs also has hardcoded a (possibly less current) copy of Mozilla which it uses if you _omit_ `ca` on any call that eventually reaches [`tls.createSecureContext`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions). ...

Comment: ... However, your server cert is selfsigned. Nothing you put or add to `ca` on the server will make that cert trusted on the browser; if there were a way for you to make a bogus cert trusted from your server then every one of a billion criminals worldwide could make their servers trusted for every website you use, like your bank and doctor, and steal all your money and personal data, which would be undesirable. The only way to make your cert trusted is to import it into the browser or the browser's OS depending on which browser(s) you use. And which is not programming or development.